# AzureSynapse Lookup UserErrorFileNotFound with Wildcard path

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am facing an odd issue where my lookup is returning a filenotfound error when I use a wildcard path. If I specify and exact file path, the lookup runs without error. However, if I replace the filename with a *, I get a filenotfound error.

The file is Data_643.json, located in my Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, under the labournavigatorfile system. The exact file path is:
labournavigatorfile/raw_data/Scraped/HeadHunter/Saudi_Arabia/Data_643.json.

If I put this exact path into the Integration dataset configuration, the pipeline runs without issue. However, as soon as I replace the 'Data_643.json' with a '*', the pipeline crashes with a filenotfound error.

What am I doing wrong? Many Thanks for any support. This must be something very simple that I am missing.

**Exact path works:**
[image: filepath]
[image: pipeline run]
[image: lookup]
[image: path]

**Wildcrad path throws error:**
[image: wildcard path]
[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 3 files in my container as `file1.json, file2.json, file3.json` as shown below:

[image]

The following is how I configured my dataset to read using wildcard with configuration same as in the image provided in the question.

[image]

- When I used this in `lookup` I got the same error:

[image]

- To overcome this, go to your lookup activity. When you want to use wildcards to read a file/files, check the `wildcard file path` option. Then specify the folder structure and use wildcard where required. The following is an image for reference.

[image]

- The following is the debug output when I run the pipeline (Each of my files had 10 rows):

[image]

Comment: You are a legend Saideep. Second time you have saved me. I had actually tried this previously but was incorrectly including the labournavigatorfile (data in your example) in the wildcard path. Removed it and everything is working. Huge thank you!